# Taylor series: $\sin x = x$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Taylor series are used to expand a function to a series of functions that sometimes makes calculations easier.

The more terms of a series we consider the more precise the solution would be.

Sometimes a rough approximation, is acceptable, when only first two terms of a series is considered.

Saying that, if we consider $\sin x = x$ (taking only first term) would that mean, that $\sin x$ is roughly equal to $x$ ? If so what does that mean, how $\sin x$ can be equal to $x$? If not, where am I wrong in my arguments?

Comment: Well, $\sin x$ can roughly be equal to $x$ around $0$ in the sense that $\tfrac{\sin x}{x} \overset{x → 0}{\longrightarrow} 1$ for example.

Comment: Yes, $\sin x$ is roughly equal to $x$, for $|x| < 1$. That is, $x$ is an approximation to $\sin x$. A better approximation comes from taking the first two terms ($x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$), an even better approximation from taking the first three terms ($x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}$), etc. For example, [$\sin (0.05) \approx 0.049979$](https://www.google.com/search?q=sin(0.05)), [$\sin(0.003) \approx 0.0029999955$](https://www.google.com/search?q=sin(0.003)), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The more terms of a series we consider the more precise the solution would be.

Yes, see below, where the black line is $\sin x$, the red is approximating using $x$, the green using $x-x^3/3!$ and the blue with $x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!$

[image]

> Sometimes a rough approximation, is acceptable, when only first two terms of a series is considered.

Yes, for even a single term, it's hard to distinguish $\sin x$ and $x$ when you plot in $[-0.5,0.5]$.

> Saying that, if we consider sin(x) = x (taking only first term) would that mean, that sin x is roughly equal to x ? If so what does that mean, how sin x can be equal to x?

Yes, it means they're approximately equal. Mathematicians and scientists use [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) to indicate the *order* or magnitude of the error. E.g.
$$\begin{align}
\sin x &= x + O(x^3)\\
\sin x &= x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^5)\\
\sin x &= x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + O(x^7)
\end{align}$$

This means that when you use $x$ for example  to approximate $\sin x$, any errors you get are proportional to $x^3$ at worst, and so long as $x$ is close to zero, $x^3$ will be small and not worth worrying about.

Formally, with Taylor series you can quantify the error, or the [remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable), in terms of some multiple of the next term in the series (although this multiple is hard to find explicitly).

Comment: it's a pleasure, I find I learn quite a bit from doing this. I never realised what a good approximation $sin(x)=x$ actually is before writing this post for example.

Answer (score 3):

It's not hard to prove that if $x \neq 0$, then $\sin{x} \neq x$. Graphically one sees

[image]

Any sufficiently smooth function, such as $\sin{x}$, is [*approximately* equal to the first term in its Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem) near where it is centered. The Taylor series for sine (centered about $x=0$) is

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \ldots.
$$

So we have that

$$ \sin{x} \approx x.$$

This approximation is pretty good for small values of $x$. As such, physicsts [somtimes use](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pend.html) this fact to make their differential equations easier to solve. They call it the [small-angle approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation).

By adding more terms, we get a better approximation.